# Define both schema name and constraint in sqlalchemy orm

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a table in SQLAlchemy ORM, where I need to specify both the schema name (for postgres) and some constraints. To specify just the schema name, one uses a dictionary:

```
class NewTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "new_table"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "schema_name"}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255), unique=True)
```

and to define just constraints the code would be:

```
class NewTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "new_table"
   
    id = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String(255))

    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint("id", name="id_pk"),
        UniqueConstraint("name")
    )
```

, using tuples.

Does someone knows how to set the schema name in the last code block, using the tuples syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the answer in the documentation:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html#orm-declarative-table-configuration

Basically, all keyword arguments must be set at the end of the constraint tuple:

```
class NewTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "new_table"
   
    id = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String(255))

    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint("id", name="id_pk"),
        UniqueConstraint("name"),
        {"schema": "schema_name"}
    )
```

Comment: With SQLAlchemy 1.3 this doesn't seem to work. Looking into upgrading to 1.4.